# calendar built-in displays error for "#include <hr_HR/calendar.all>"

Tags: linux-mint, calendar

For Linux Mint 18.3, 32-bit, MATE desktop 1.18.0.

In BASH, typing `calendar` produces the following error.

```
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $ calendar
In file included from /usr/share/calendar/calendar.all:23:0,
                 from <stdin>:16:
/usr/share/calendar/calendar.croatian:10:0: fatal error: hr_HR/calendar.all: No such file or directory
 #include <hr_HR/calendar.all>
 ^
compilation terminated.
Feb 15  Galileo Galilei born in Pisa, Italy, 1564

------ list of dates ------ 

Feb 16  Stephen Decatur burns US frigate in Tripoli, 1804
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $
```

I've located the cited file *calendar.croatian* and offending line:

```
/*
 * Croatian calendar files
 *
 * $FreeBSD$
 */

#ifndef _calendar_croatian_
#define _calendar_croatian_
/* THIS IS THE LINE CITED IN THE ERROR */
#include <hr_HR/calendar.all>

#endif /* !_calendar_croatian_ */
```

But I have no idea what to do. Delete the line? Edit it? Or?

Or is the best solution to edit `calendar.all` and simply delete the line `#include <calendar.croatian>`? Although I'd like to actually fix the problem if possible rather than simply deleting things...

---

**EDIT #1: Unable to reinstall bsdmainutils**

Tried the suggestion to reinstall *basmainutils* but it seems not to exist on my system AND I'm unable to use *apt-get* to download and install it.

```
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bsdmainutils
[sudo] password for rbv: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of bsdmainutils is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $
```

With specific regard to reinstall, it does not seem to already exist on this 32-bit Linux Mint / MATE computer.

---

**EDIT #2: Attempt to use dpkg-query to identify owner of basmainutils**

In response to commentor suggestion, ran the following:

```
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $ dpkg-query -S /usr/share/calendar/calendar.all
bsdmainutils: /usr/share/calendar/calendar.all
```

This seemingly indicates that although I can't use `about` or `which` or `apropos` or `man` to find anything about *bsdmainutils*, it's evidently the owner of *calendar.all*.

Note also that the `locate bsdmainutils` command produced the following:

```
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $ locate bsdmainutils
/etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
/etc/default/bsdmainutils
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/README
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/calendarJudaic.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/copyright
/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/source.data.gz
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bsdmainutils
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsdmainutils.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsdmainutils.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsdmainutils.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsdmainutils.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsdmainutils.prerm
rbv@rbv-F80Q ~ $
```

So on the one hand *bsdmainutils* seems to not be available to *apt-get* and so on, yet there are some *basmainutils* files present on the system.

---

**EDIT #3: Circumvention found, see my answer to my own question, below**

Although `apt-get` was unable to to locate and so reinstall *bsdmainutils*, the *Synaptic* package manager did list and so could reinstall it. Details below.

Comment: Did something happen recently with the bsdmainutils package? Perhaps reinstall that?

Comment: Interesting; I must have found old information. Can you run `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/calendar/calendar.all` to see what package owns that file?

Comment: See edit #2. Ran the command which indicated bsdmainutils was owner of calendar.all. But otherwise bsdmainutils is "invisible" to the commands I normally use to get information about a program or file. At the same time "locate" found several bsdmainutils files. Confusing...

Comment: Interesting; glad you got to the bottom of it; instead of editing the title, simply accept your own answer. That's how Stack Exchange indicates that a problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I "fixed" the problem -- but I'm not happy with the way it ended up being fixed.

The solution was to use *Synaptic* rather than `apt-get` on the command line to reinstall *bsdmainutils*. After doing that the error with *calendar* no longer occurred.

But this reflects another recurring problem I'm having ala  **[Synaptic won't list programs that apt-get will install...?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418114/synaptic-wont-list-programs-that-apt-get-will-install)**

In this instance the opposite of that existing post's issue occurred: Synaptic "knew about" a package that `apt-get` on the CLI did not. Point being that I can't figure out why `apt-get` often finds programs that *Synaptic* doesn't list. And in this instance, the opposite...

---

**Edit #1: Problem may occur because *Bleachbit* deletes *calendar* files**

IF you reinstall *bsdmainutils* and *calendar* again works properly, AND later the same problem recurs, THEN note that depending on settings,  *Bleachbit* may be deleting files contained in `/usr/share/calendar/`. Use **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Whitelist** -> **Add folder** -> to exclude the files contained in `/usr/share/calendar` from deletion. **NOTE** that you may need to perform this operation for both *Bleachbit as root* and *Bleachbit* in user-account modes...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Linux Mint system to try this on, so I'm basing it on [several](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=259369) - [other](https://superuser.com/questions/102449/how-to-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get) - [pages](https://debian-administration.org/article/176/Reinstalling_packages_to_fix_problems.) who demonstrated the `--reinstall` option:

```
apt-get install --reinstall bsdmainutils
```

The assumption here is that something inadvertently removed the `/usr/share/calendar/hr_HR/calendar.all` file. We're asking the package manager to reinstall the package, which should replace that file.

Comment: Per my edit to my original question, bsdmainutils seems not to exist on my computer AND apt-get can't download it...